# How can a C program restart itself once using execve?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a C program that restarts itself once. My approach was to `fork` and in the child process call `execve`. I thought I would see `Hello` twice printed. This here prints `main` twice, but even so if I comment out `execve`, so I assume I'm not correctly using `execve` here. The binary is called "restartOnce".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    printf("Main.\n");
    if (pid == 0) { 
        char *argv = "hello"; // To silence gcc compiler warning.
        char *env  = "world"; // To silence gcc compiler warning.  
        execve("restartOnce", &argv, &env);
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Done.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2nd and 3rd arguments are pointers to a `NULL` terminated array of `char*`. You shouldn't just silence warnings.

Comment: What would print "Hello", at all? Anyway, even if you get this to work, it would fork a never-ending series of descendants. The first instance would fork a child, that child would fork a child, that child would fork a child, etc., forever. It's essentially a fork bomb.

Comment: @KenThomases This I am aware of, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Actually, what are you trying to accomplish with this fork + restart thing?  I know lots of software needs to detach itself from the parent process ID to put itself in the background - this is common - but it doesn't need to restart itself, it just does its main job in the child after fork, with no exec required.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but I see two things to attend to. We have to get the `execve()` call right, plus we have to avoid a fork bomb, and this code should do it.

There are lots of ways to avoid a fork bomb, but I chose to set something in the environment, and when the child sees this environment variable, it will know not to continue.

So `execve()` requires its own `argv`, which is an array of pointers to individual strings (with a NULL pointer at the end), and it's entirely legit to pass the same parameter you got from main.

The third parameter is like `argv`, but it's a list of environment variables instead of command line arguments. It has things like `TERM=vt100`, `PATH=/bin/...`, and many others.  Though you can fetch environment variables individually with `getenv("PATH")`, Unix/Linux systems provide an argv-like variable `environ`.

This variable is declared in `<unistd.h>` but requires the `_GNU_SOURCE` macro to be defined to expose it.

This done, you can call safely call `execve` this way:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

    ...
    execve("restartOnce", argv, environ);
```

To avoid a fork bomb, one of the first thing the program does is look for the environment variable `FORKBOMB` - if this is set, we're in the child process and should stop forking other children, perhaps doing something else instead (the real work of the program?)

But if we're in the parent - no variable seen - we actively **set** the variable by putting it in our own environment that's seen by the child processes: `putenv("FORKBOMB=no");`

A minor addition: the very first thing the program does is report that it's started up, and it provides its own process ID just so you know what it's doing.

Maybe I misunderstand the problem, but this is how I'd solve what I imagine you're asking:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE // for "environ"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Main in pid %d.\n", getpid() );

    if (getenv("FORKBOMB") != 0)
    {
        printf("**We're in the second child, no more forking\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    putenv("FORKBOMB=no");

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        execve("restartOnce", argv, environ);
    } else {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Done.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are quite a few other ways to avoid the fork bomb, but this is as good as any to get the idea across, and others might chime in with their favorites.

**EDIT** But as I think about this, I'm pretty sure this should not be necessary no matter what you're trying to accomplish unless this is just a learning exercise.

The two things I can imagine are:

1) You need to detach from the parent process so you can run in the background, like a daemon process. In that case, you don't have to exec, just do the daemon work in the child process.

2) If the program has altered *itself* - perhaps downloaded an updated version of itself, then it does have to call exec to get the new executable, but a `fork()` would not be required.

So I'm not sure we (or at least I) know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive and very helpful reply and apologies for the unclear question. My assignment is to "Write a program that starts itself exactly once." It should be possible using not more but `execve`, `fork`, `wait`.

Comment: so... did this help you with the assignment?

Comment: For your suggestion 1): I need to use execve. 2) The program does not alter itself and per the instructions it seems as if `fork` is part of the solution.